# Physics behind Uranium metal bars being "self-shielding"

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I was looking through some old documents and pitching them from my time at uni.  In there, I found some materials handling notes, and one regarding the handling Uranium metal bars.  Basically, it said that they didn't require any special handling. As a thought experiment, this makes sense as the bars are just purified ore and thereby very dense and the radiation would be just surface emission.  Is this true?

Comment: Enriched or not? How enriched?

Comment: @JonCuster not enriched

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with* high-energy X-ray equipment (as used in medical oncology) which had shielding components made of metallic uranium. Pretty much the only material property that matters when shielding against high-energy photons is how much matter you can put between yourself and the source.  Uranium is a good choice for shielding when you need the shield to fit into a very small space. It is one of the most dense materials known, and it is much less expensive** than other similarly dense materials.

Uranium is only weakly radioactive.

The main safety concern with handling natural uranium or depleted uranium is, it oxidizes on exposure to air, and the oxide readily contaminates anything that comes into contact with it. There are various reasons why you don't want to ingest or inhale uranium in any form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#Human_exposure), and it would be inconsiderate to your fellow human beings to release it into the environment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_in_the_environment).

*Enriched* uranium has a whole other set of safety concerns. People who have been physically close to unplanned nuclear chain reactions have suffered severe health effects, up to and including slow, agonizing death. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticality_accident

---

* My own job did not require me to ever open any covers that would let me see those components. I only know about it because I read in the manuals about the need to notify appropriate regulatory agencies if those parts were to be removed or if the equipment was to be decommissioned.

** Especially, depleted uranium, since the nuclear industry produces more of that stuff as a by-product than they know what to do with.

Comment: U-238 is an alpha emitter, so really only dangerous if inside your body (inhalation, ingestion). U-235 is a different beast.